# How to check value of input type image in php or smarty?

Tags: php, html, smarty

How can i check the value of input type image ?

I want to hide the image if the value is 0.

How will i do it?

I have this code:

```
<input type="image" src="/pc/images/mute.png" class="actionmute" value="1">
<input type="image" src="/pc/images/talk.png" class="actionUnmute" style="display:none" value="0">
```

I want to check the value of the image

if value == 0 i want the image display:none

if value == 1 i want the image display:block

thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `$('[type=image][value=0]').attr("style", "display:none");` try it using jquery.. and immediately all inputs with `type = image` and `value = 0` will have `style = display:none`